# How do I use face masks when texture painting on UV maps?

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

It shows the masked faces in the 2D view but it doesn't prevent me from painting over them.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to prevent painting on some faces in the Image Editor it this is what you're looking for

Comment: yes that is what im looking for